# five rows/records/arrays returned by innerJoin/leftJoin to be as one row/record/array - php

Tags: php, left-join, inner-join

I have table: Courses and table: Sessions. А course may have multiple sessions(for example 5 sessions). What I have to do(maybe in PHP) to transform these 5 records of course and sessions in to one record/array? I've tried array_merge() and array_merge recursively(), but without success.

If you need the exact data/rows/record/arrays that I recieve, I'll posted them.

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
public function getCourses($dateFrom, $dateTo)
{
$select = $this->_dbTableCourseTimetables->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false); 
$select->from(array('a' => 'course_timetables'), 'a.id_course_timetables'); 
$select->where('b.start_time >= ?', $dateFrom);
$select->where('b.end_time <= ?', $dateTo);
$select->where('b.isActive >= ?', 'yes');
$select->joinInner(array('b' => 'course_sessions'), 'a.id_course_timetables =  b.id_course_timetables', 'b.id_course_sessions');
echo $select;
return $this->_dbTableCourseTimetables->fetchAll($select)->toArray();
}
```

This is my Zend query, which produces this SQL:

`SELECT a.id_course_timetables, b.id_course_sessions FROM course_timetables AS a INNER JOIN course_sessions AS b ON a.id_course_timetables = b.id_course_timetables WHERE (b.start_time >= '1332745200') AND (b.end_time <= '1333350000') AND (b.isActive >= 'yes')`

Which if I execute it. It returns:

```
id_course | id_course_sessions
--------- ----------------- 
303       533 
303       534  
303       532 
304       535
```

And when I loop through foreach() It is rendering me four items. I actually want to be two items, because the courses are only two. Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

P.S. what incredible editor....

Comment: @DanielDimitrov - please move your code in comments to the actual question, where they can be correctly formatted (four spaces before each line). Then delete the comments - keep it readable for your readers `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do such an implementation.

```
$array = array();

foreach($your_Result_array as $k => $v) {
      if (empty($array[$k])) {
        $array[$k] = array($v);
      } else {
        array_push($array[$k], array($v));
      }
}

var_dump($array);

//Your array will be like [303] => array(534, 532, 533), [304] = array(535)
```

Hope this helps